# Appium is not identifying the device

Tags: appium

I am new to Appium. I did set the configurations and tried to test samsung galaxy tab of android kitkat 4.4.2. The device is not getting identified by the appium. The device is getting identified by the android but not appium.Please do help me to resolve the issue.

I am giving the coding here

```
@BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        /*
         * File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")); File
         * appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "../../../apps/ApiDemos/bin"); File
         * app = new File(appDir, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");
         */
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName","Selendroid");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "4d0001f745b350e1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"chrome");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
                capabilities);

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void apiDemo() {
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

    }
```

and when I am running this,Appium is showing as 0 connected devices.

But the same configured Appium is working fine with emulator of 4.3.

Comment: Anybody please answer the question.  I am stuck with this issue for the past two days. Not able to proceed further

Comment: Could you please just open appium gui and try to connect to the device? Please provide the appium log if no connection.

Comment: Are the drivers installed correctly for your device? Is android debug option enabled in device?

Answer (score 0):

1. check your cable connection
2. Are you able to see your device on adb devices directly ?
3. if your not able see on adb devices , den please enable usb debugging and tap on yes on the prompt that will authorize your device.
4. check drivers for your device and install
5. check connecting with debugging other in other mode instead of mtp mode

Comment: I am able to see devices on adb. It is taking long time to identify the device by appium. I am getting connection error